# How to reopen differential review in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I created review for development branch in phabricator, updated it several times and than pushed branch for testing. Review was not finished but phabricator automatically closed it.

I can create another differential review, but all comments and updates will be in old...

So is there a way to reopen closed review?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I knew there was a better way!

EDIT: While the old answer works... it is **not** how to do this. Instead do this:

1. Go to the config section, and chose the differential group.
2. Find the option **differential.allow-reopen**
3. Set value to "**Enable reopen**" and save config entry.
4. Navigate to closed differential review.
5. Go to the bottom, and find the **Leap Into Action** section.
6. Chose the action **reopen** and add a comment
7. Press Clowncopterize and presto! Reopened!

No need to hack the database.

Also, take a look at the repository settings, to set up auto closing the way you want it.

1. Go to the Repositories administration section
2. Press edit for the repository you wish to manage
3. Chose the tracking tab
4. In the *Application Configuration* section you see two settings: **Autoclose** and **Autoclose Branches**.

I have set **Autoclose** to *Enabled*, and **Autoclose Branches** to *master*. That way only pushes to origin/master will autoclose a differential review.

---------OLD Answer--------

What sberry is suggesting is to SSH into your server, and open an MySql prompt:

```
mysql> USE phabricator_differential;
mysql> select status from differential_revision where id=5; (If your revision is D5 for example)
```

Notice that your status is not 0. It is most likely 3 for closed.

```
mysql> update differential_revision set status=0 where id=5;
```

Now your revision is open again.

I feel that this is quite cumbersome, but never the less it achieves the goal. I hope there is somebody who can suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: I actually patched our installation of phabricator to allow admin users to do this via a drop down.  If we didn't have so many unrelated patches already I would push this upstream.

Comment: That would be a cool feature to have added. If you have the time, I would love it if you made a pull request for this change.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, what other patches have you made? I have just started using Phabricator on my team, and when we get the hang of a process that works for us, we will roll it out to all teams. So any insight on short commings or bad workflows is highly appreciated.

Comment: The biggest patch allows each user to select unified diffs vs side by side.  We had a couple people that were really used to the udiffs and it was a deal breaker.  Support for viewing standalone diffs as udiffs was already available but not in the normal view.  Others involved extending LDAP support, and some integration with JIRA.

Comment: What is the "config section"? How do I get there?